# jquery image hover keeps growing as many times as i hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got this strange behaviour
when i do a slow hover on image everything is working, the image grows and on hover out the image shrinks.

But when i repeat the hover fast the image keeps growing and growing and the position is changing according to the hover speed

**Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4C2YJ/1/)**

**Jquery**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var cont_left = $("#container").position().left;
    $("a img").hover(function () {
        // hover in
        $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 1);
        current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
        current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: (current_w * 1.3),
            height: (current_h * 1.3),
            left: "-=50",
            top: "-=50"
        }, 300);
    }, function () {

        // hover out
        $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 0);
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: current_w + 'px',
            height: current_h + 'px',
            left: "+=50",
            top: "+=50"
        }, 300);
    });

    $(".img").each(function (index) {
        var left = (index * 160) + cont_left;
        $(this).css("left", left + "px");
    });
});
```

Please advise how to i fix the image grow and position.
P.S: every image has a different dimentions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are the key to the problem:

```
    current_h = $(this, 'img')[0].height;
    current_w = $(this, 'img')[0].width;
```

When you `.stop` the image-growing animation, it doesn't shrink back to its original size (unless you set [**its second param**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to `true` - but you assign `false` to it explicitly, and I assume you know what you're doing here). So both dimensions are set to the increased value actually.

Solution is simple: always use the original size of the images:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current_h, current_w;
    // ... 
    current_h = current_h || $(this, 'img')[0].height;
    current_w = current_w || $(this, 'img')[0].width;
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mkv9Y/).

---

Two sidenotes here. First, there's a similar problem with positioning of these elements: move too fast, and your images will shift to the left-upper or right-lower corners (depending on the phase); that's because, again, animation is done against the *current* state of things, which is not the same as original when the previous animation is stopped with `.stop(true, false)`.

Second, using `$(this, 'img')[0]` in this case is essentially the same as just `this`. Remember, in event handlers `this` corresponds to the DOM element having this event handler assigned.

So this is how it can be done ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MvtSn/2/)):

```
$("a img").hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.img').css('z-index', 1);

    var orig = $this.data('orig');
    if (!orig) { // caching the original sizes via `jQuery.data`
        orig = {
            width: this.width,
            height: this.height
        };
        $this.data('orig', orig);
    }
    $this.stop(true, false).animate({
        width: orig.width * 1.3,
        height: orig.height * 1.3,
        left: -(orig.width * 0.3 / 2),
        top: -(orig.height * 0.3 / 2)
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        orig = $this.data('orig');
    if (!orig) {
        return false;
        // actually, it should never be here, 
        // as calling 'mouseleave' without data precached 
        // means 'mouseenter' has been never called
    }
    $this.closest('.img').css('z-index', 0);
    $this.stop(true, false).animate({
        width: orig.width,
        height: orig.height,
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: +1 but what if the images are different sizes though?

Comment: Then they can be stored in arrays (and accessed by element's index) - or, as in your post, in datasets (I'd actually prefer jQuery's data functions).

Comment: you right, there is a position problem and another problem is that every img has a different width and height

Comment: @MikeTishler Check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5uT5/); is it what you want?

Comment: Looking GREAT! just a small js fiddle error in row 19 (js part)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you hover quickly, your values `current_h` and `current_w` don't measure the ***original*** height and width, but the current height and width. Thus, every time, you're increasing the value.

### Solution

I've used a simple `.each()` function here to set the original height and width of each image as data attributes which can then be accessed when you're setting `current_h` and `current_w`.

```
$('img').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).attr({
         "data-original-width": $(this).width(), 
         "data-original-height": $(this).height()
    });
});

current_h = $(this).attr("data-original-height");
current_w = $(this).attr("data-original-width");
```

***[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4C2YJ/6/)***

You don't have to use the each function though. If you know the height and width of the images before rendering, then you can set these as data attributes in your HTML

Comment: This should be done in `window.load` handler, not `window.ready`.

Comment: the image is not growing in your fiddle

Comment: @MikeTishler Apologies. Works now.

Comment: @MikeTishler In light of your comments above. Check the fiddle to see changes for keeping the positioning correct.